# jquery change scrollbars to buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, onscroll

Im trying to remove the scrollbars and replace them with up/down buttons.

Im nearly there, everything works, I just want to remove the 'up' button when you are scrolled right to the top of the container.  right now Ive just hidden it as a default and an onscroll event on the container, and then just do this to make the scroll button appear:

```
 function OnScrollDiv (div) {
        $(".up").show();     
    }
```

But if you scroll back up, the up button stays, of course.

Now I dont understand why my alternative wont work!  What I want to do is just check at the scroll event whether the scrollTop() value is 0, if it is, dont show it.  I dont know javascript, but I would imagine it would look like:

```
  function OnScrollDiv (div) {
var n = $("#prodcont").scrollTop();
if (n = 0) {
    //nothing
} 
else {
    $(".up").show();            
}
```

But alas, this does not work.  At all.  Any suggestions?!

Comment: Please, please, please do not remove the scrollbars. This is an awful user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of onscroll event provided by window. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onscroll)

```
window.onscroll = scroll;

function scroll () {
    console.log("scroll event detected! " + window.pageXOffset + " " + window.pageYOffset);
    if(window.pageXOffset == 0 && window.pageYOffset == 0)
        console.log('hide buttons');
}
```